# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'announcementCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, controller, undefined-function

I am getting this error that 'announcementCtrl' is not a function? Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here. It clearly is defined so what's happening? 
This is my javascript:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('announcementApp', []);

  app.controller('announcementCtrl', function() {
    this.announcements = announcementsArray;
  });


  var announcementsArray = [
    {
      type: 'UPDATE',
      announcement: 'DISA Maps are almost complete! Look foward to reporting out at the project share next week.'
    },
    {
      type: 'SHOUT-OUT',
      announcement: 'Great work to Lawson and Patrick on Innovation Cell. We are gaining more strategic position and proving our value everyday.'
    },
    {
      type: 'EVENT',
      announcement: 'Dr. Chipley will be visiting 3/20/2015 to talk Cybersecurity'
    }
  ];


})();
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="row row2" ng-app="announcementApp">
  <section class="sub-box client-box">
    <div class="announcements" ng-controller="announcementCtrl as announcements">

    <div class="announcement-block" ng-repeat="eachAnnouncement in announcements">
       <div class="event-highlight update"></div>
       <div class="wrap">
          <div class="announcement-description">{{eachAnnouncement.type}}</div>
          <div class="announcement">{{eachAnnouncement.announcement}}</div>
       </div>
    </div>

   </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if you've just emitted this from your code or not but have you included your javascript file inside <script> tags?

Comment: @peppermcknight yes I have. It's the first js file I call out of my controllers.

Comment: *It's the first js file I call out of my controllers* Does any other JS file also contain `angular.module('announcementApp', []);`?

Comment: No I have a different module for the entire body that the other files reference. The problem that I am getting is that I think the app.js file is not being called at all? I tried logging some stuff in the control and it did not log.

Comment: Fixed it! Just had to put all the modules referring to my parent module in one folder then add the "announcementApp" module as a dependency under my parent.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you mixed up the controllers 'handle' and the property you want to access. Since you are not injecting `$scope`  `ng-controller="announcementCtrl as announcements"` declares announcements as a kind of 'handler' for `this`. Inside your controller you declare `this.announcements` to be your array. So it should be `ng-repeat="eachAnnouncement in announcements.announcements"` (first announcements = this in your controller, second = the array)

Look at the code example in the documentation: [AngularJS: ngController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)

**Edit:** Maybe the answer was a bit confusing, but it works allright: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f3dj2Ljy/1/)

I renamed your controller handle to 'ctrl' to make it more clear what was changed.

Comment: still getting the error Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'announcementCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: Fixed it! Just had to put all the modules referring to my parent module in one folder then add the "announcementApp" module as a dependency under my parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$scope` to save your values:

```
  app.controller('announcementCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.announcements = announcementsArray;
  });
```

After i did that i receive the same error only when i comment my `controller` definition at all.

Also, clear cache of your browser.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/oHHEtRgLpVbEcbao5U9o?p=preview